# link source to svn in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have svn repository with source code which I want to link (right click Team-Share) to svn in eclipse in order to be able to commit, update etc.

There is a weird problem, when project in eclipse is marked as maven project then svn is linked correctly, it extracts repository url, user name, password etc. But if project is not maven (java project for example) then eclipse for some reason can't find repository url and treats project as new being committed to svn.

How can I link non maven project to svn version control?

```
Maven Integration for Eclipse (Required)    0.12.1.20110112-1712
org.maven.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group Sonatype, Inc.

Subclipse (Required)    1.8.3   
org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.feature.group   tigris.org

Subversion Client Adapter (Required)    1.8.0
org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.feature.feature.group   tigris.org

Subversion JavaHL Native Library Adapter (Required) 1.7.1.1
org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.feature.feature.group    tigris.org
```

**UPD** root of the problem is found. This is due to using linked source directories. When eclipse project is placed outside svn working tree, eclipse can not extract svn parameters (repository url etc...), but when eclipse project is placed in svn working tree team feature works flawlessly.

Comment: Could you add the following information: eclipse version, plugin you are using for svn integration (Subversive or Subclipse) and version of that, version of m2e (or m2eclipse) you are using?

Comment: @mliebelt, added necessary information

Comment: What do you mean with "treats project as new being committed to svn"?.

Comment: @Robert, it does not find repository url in svn metadata, instead it suggests me to select project path and then commit project

Comment: @misha: If you have an unshared project there are no SVN meta data. By sharing the project the meta data are initially created.

Comment: @Robert, project source code is already in svn, I just want to enable it in eclipse

Comment: @misha: Close the project and re-open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such weird behaviour is due to using linked source directories. When eclipse project is placed outside svn working tree, eclipse can not extract svn parameters (repository url etc...), but when eclipse project is placed in svn working tree team feature works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

This should work but sometimes, Eclipse "forgets" the sharing information.

The solution is to share it again. Eclipse will read the existing repo info and use that (instead of creating a new repo).

If in doubt, make a backup of the project folder, first; SVN doesn't store any project-specific information outside of the project folders, so restoring from the backup will get you exactly what you had before.

Comment: `The solution is to share it again. Eclipse will read the existing repo info and use that (instead of creating a new repo).` That happens, for some reason, only for maven projects. For java projects it treats project as being not in svn.

Comment: Just checking: You made sure the project contains `.svn` folders and they are not empty?

Comment: yes, it is correct svn working copy, I can work with it using svn client (e.g. TortoiseSVN). I can correctly share maven project, but I can't share the same project (when it is not under maven in eclipse).

Comment: This is extremely odd. What happens when you click on "Share..."?

Comment: it suggests me to select existing connection to svn (which is wrong) or to create new connection to svn.

Comment: Existing connection is not extracted from svn metadata, it is manually created in this dialog in one of previous tries to share project. One more thing, I noted that team-share works correctly on imported maven project and even if I enable maven dependency management on existing java project that does not make sense.

Comment: Maybe it does. It seems that Eclipse doesn't take the information from the .svn folders but it saves the info somewhere when you import the project - if you share the project again, this saved information is used (and not what's in the .svn folders). Try this: Share the project my manually specifying the URL. Does Eclipse remember this when you need to share the project again? If so, file a bug. IMO, Eclipse should use the .svn info.

Comment: Seems, I know what is the root of the problem! Maven project is placed in svn working copy, while non maven project is placed outside svn working copy and uses linked source directories which is in svn. I tried to create java project in svn working copy and it enabled team features flawlessly. How to link to svn linked source directory?

Comment: Don't use linked source directories with SVN. Copy the sources into your new project (there should be a checkbox for this when you create the project)